# Chair Caster size no longer available

Tags: furniture

I have some older high end kitchen chairs that use threaded plastic casters that are failing.  They are 3/16 18.  This is a non-standard size for a threaded caster I guess since I cannot find any anywhere.  Can I rethread something like a 1/4 caster to 3/16 or do I have to get a bigger size in order to do this?  The chair uses a welded on nut to hold the caster.  Could I maybe tap that out to a larger size?

Comment: Pictures are always helpful for questions like this.

Comment: Drill and tap for 1/4-20, plenty of casters available in that size.

Comment: Pics _are_ helpful... Does the plastic part just push in? If so, pull it out and put something else in.

Comment: Have you tried going to an old-fashioned hardware store with one of the casters in hand to see if they have a match?

Comment: Just make sure you use the right bit size for the tap.  I think it is a #7 size bit(13/64)